# Как установить и пользоваться технологиями Java EE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, ide

Недавно узнал, что в IntelliJ IDEA Comunity нету поддержки Java EE, а в версии ultimate она есть. И еще на сайте oracle я нашел [ссылку](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) на скачивание Java EE SDK. После чего у меня появилось пару вопросов:

1. Почему в сomunity версии нету возможности использовать Java EE?
2. Могу ли я просто скачать/установить Java EE?
3. Обязательно ли использовать ultimate версию, чтобы использовать Java EE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Потому, что EE - это аббревиатура от Enterpise Edition. Основные пользователи этого стандарта - корпорации, применяющие его для получения коммерческой выгоды. Вполне логично, что для этого должна использоваться коммерческая лицензия.
2. Можете.
3. Не обязательно. IDE вообще не обязательна, можно и без неё программировать.

Answer (score 3):

Используем в разработке IDEA of community edition. Как пример, используем velocity, хотя и на сайте написано, что velocity доступен только в ultimate edition. Не заморачивайтесь насчет ultimate и разбирайтесь сначала с **Java SE**.

К Java standard edition относится: awt, swing, nio, math и т.д.

К Java enterprise edition относится: EJB, JSS, JSP, JSF, JPA, JSTL и т.д.

**Java Platform, Standard Edition, сокращенно Java SE (ранее Java 2 Standard Edition или J2SE)** — стандартная версия платформы Java 2, предназначенная для создания и исполнения апплетов и приложений, рассчитанных на индивидуальное пользование или на использование в масштабах малого предприятия. Не включает в себя многие возможности, предоставляемые более мощной и расширенной платформой Java 2 Enterprise Edition (J2EE), рассчитанной на создание коммерческих приложений масштаба крупных и средних предприятий.

**Java Platform, Enterprise Edition, сокращенно Java EE (до версии 5.0 — Java 2 Enterprise Edition или J2EE)** — набор спецификаций и соответствующей документации для языка Java, описывающей архитектуру серверной платформы для задач средних и крупных предприятий.
Спецификации детализированы настолько, чтобы обеспечить переносимость программ с одной реализации платформы на другую. Основная цель спецификаций — обеспечить масштабируемость приложений и целостность данных во время работы системы. J2EE во многом ориентирована на использование её через веб как в интернете, так и в локальных сетях. Вся спецификация создаётся и утверждается через JCP (Java Community Process) в рамках инициативы Sun Microsystems Inc.
J2EE является промышленной технологией и в основном используется в высокопроизводительных проектах, в которых необходима надежность, масштабируемость, гибкость.
Популярности J2EE также способствует то, что Sun предлагает бесплатный комплект разработки, SDK, позволяющий предприятиям разрабатывать свои системы, не тратя больших средств. В этот комплект входит сервер приложений с лицензией для разработки.